# Why is the output of the following two segments different?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i = 5;   // here
    if (--i){
        printf("%d ", i);
        main();
    }
}
```

Output: 4 3 2 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int i = 5;   // here
     if (--i){
        printf("%d ", i);
        main();
    }
}
```

Output: 4 4 4 4... (Segmentation fault)

Any idea how static int variable is taken into account only once and int is taken over and over again?

Comment: We ordinarily expect folks to perform some due diligence before posing a question here.  So what did your research into the significance of the `static` keyword in C tell you?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new here. I even deleted this post, but then undeleted it thinking that someone else might also have the same question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a `static` variable in a function, the function "remembers" the last value of the variable even after it terminates.

```
void Foo() {
    static int x = 5;
}
```

In the example above, you are telling the compiler that `x` shall be "remembered" and has an initial value of `5`. Subsequent calls to `Foo()` does not reassign `x` a value of `5`, but uses the previously remembered value.

In contrast:

```
void Bar() {
    int x = 5;
}
```

Here, you are telling the compiler that everytime `Bar()` executes, a new variable `x` is to be created on the stack and assigned a value of `5`.

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared as `static` inside of a function retains its value each time the function is called.  It is initialized only once, when the function is first called.  So when the function calls itself the value of `i` is retained from the prior call.

A local variable that is *not* `static` is specific to a given call of a function, so each time the function is called a new copy of the variable is created and initialized.  This results in `i` being 5 each time, which in turn results in infinite recursion leading to a stack overflow and a core dump.